# Sitecore publishing service files for CD

Tags: publishing-service

I've installed the publishing Service on my Xp0 environment. That works fine so far. Now I want to install it on my XP1 environment and in the installationguide for 3.1.3 for the publishing Service I've found some upgrade instruktions from 3.1.1 that I need to copy some files to my CD too. But I am not able to find any install instructions in the manual what I have to do on installation for the CD server. So I am a bit unsure what I have to do on the CD for the Publishing Service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy All the mentioned dlls in CD Server bin Folder and make sure you have `Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config` file with below configs exists in `App_Config\Modules\PublishingService path`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" >

  <sitecore >
    < !-- < hooks > -- >
      < !-- < hook type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.PublishTargetEventsHook, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" /> -- >
    < !-- < /hooks > -- >

    <!--
    SITECORE EVENTS
    -->
    <events>
      <event name="publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetSearchIndexRebuildHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="RebuildTargetSearchIndex">
          <IndexNames hint="list:AddIndex">
            <index>sitecore_web_index</index>
          </IndexNames>
        </handler>
      </event>

      <event name="publishingservice:cache:clear">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetDataCacheClearHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="ClearTargetDataCaches" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```